# Proper way to close reactor netty HttpClient

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

Reactor netty `HttpClient` does not have a method to close or shutdown the handle. What is the correct way of releasing resources of HttpClient?

As per document When I create a HttpClient using `HttpClient client = HttpClient.create();`  this will internally create a default connection pool. How can I make sure that connection pool is released properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection pool is not used by other `HttpClient`s, you can dispose it with invoking `client.configuration().connectionProvider().dispose()/disposeLater()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There is no document about this in the official documentation. Can document be updated for this? Also it would be better to have a method to release resources of HttpClient.

Comment: Please open a feature request in Reactor Netty issue tracker.